# method fitBounds() only zooms to single marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have rendered a `map` with markers, which are saved as long lat values in a local `xlsx` file.
My aim is to automatically zoom to all markers, which are loaded via an input file button. For this I am using the `fitbounds()` method from `googlemaps API`.

**Partial Example**

```
function handleFile(e) {

    //Get the files from Upload control
    var files = e.target.files;
    var i, f;

 //Loop through files
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;

            var result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

            var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
            sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /* iterate through sheets */
                //Convert the cell value to Json
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);


                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result = roa;

                }
            });

           //create global infoWindow object
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var i, newMarker;


 var gmarkers = [];

 //loop over json format 
 for (i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
    var data = result[i];
    //extract Lat Long values from result
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);

    //creating a marker and putting it on the map
    newMarker = new  google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map

    });

    gmarkers.push(newMarker);

    }

    for (var i=0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(gmarkers[i].position.lat(), gmarkers[i].position.lng());
        bounds.extend(loc);         
    }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

              }
           }

       }

    };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

   }
```

But if I run my html file, it zooms just to one marker. I suppose that it is the first marker of the gmarkers array.

[image]

However I want to achieve following result, with the full extent of my uploaded marker:

[image]

In my `main.html` you can see my `initMap()` function and the function which is called if the document is ready. In the `document ready` function the `handlefunction ()` is called.

```
 var map;
 //Change event to dropdownlist
 $(document).ready(function(){

    a = $('#input-id').fileinput({
        'showUpload': false,
        'showPreview': false,
        'showCaption': false

         });     

    a.change(handleFile);
});

function initMap() {                                            
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 48.7758459, lng: 9.1829321},
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeControl: false

    });

  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Where is the `result` data?

Comment: with SheetJS I parsed my xlxs file, which returnds a  table in json format. Based on the json format I saved result[i] to tha variable data. I edited my post above.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code.  Move the initialization of the bounds outside the loop.

```
for (var i=0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(gmarkers[i].position.lat(), gmarkers[i].position.lng());
    bounds.extend(loc);         
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

should be:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i=0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(gmarkers[i].position.lat(), gmarkers[i].position.lng());
    bounds.extend(loc);         
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gp9uqvef/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var result = [{
  Latitude: 37.4419,
  Longitude: -122.1419
}, {
  Latitude: 37.44,
  Longitude: -122.14
}, {
  Latitude: 40.44,
  Longitude: -75.14
}]

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var gmarkers = [];

  //loop over json format 
  for (i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
    var data = result[i];
    //extract Lat Long values from result
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);

    //creating a marker and putting it on the map
    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
    gmarkers.push(newMarker);
  }
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(gmarkers[i].position.lat(), gmarkers[i].position.lng());
    bounds.extend(loc);
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I tried it out, but if I move the initialization of the bounds outside the loop, my Firefox crashes and I got a timeout Error "Script terminated by timeout at:..."

Comment: Send the `result` object and a self-contained snippet that allows reproduction of the issue

Comment: what do you mean by _zoom a marker_? do you actually mean it only **shows* one marker at the moment but the expected behaviour is 3 as in the screenshots above?

Comment: I want to set the view on all 3 markers automatically.

Comment: in your example the result json object is global, and you can work with it in the initialize function.
in my example the result data is created locally in the handlefile function, 
and therefore I can't call gmarkers in my initMap function. In my post below I added my `initMap()` function and 
the function which is called if the `document is ready`. In the document ready function there is a change event, 
that calls the handlfunction.

Comment: create bounds **outside** the outer loop.

Comment: Please see my comment above, Firefox crashes if I create bounds **outside** the loop

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**

Answer (score -1):

This is *another approach* for your problem **within 35 lines of code**. 
Make sure you pass the JSON object the right way and that you declare your classes within the appropriate lexical scope.

**Make sure** the JSON Object returns something like this:

```
    const coords = [
      {lat: 42.4, lng: 1.55},
      {lat: 43.42, lng: 2.48},
      {lat: 45.43, lng: 4.9}
    ];
```

**Note I have changed `result` to a more meaningful `coords` array of objects.**

```
// Create your markers without worrying about scope and without extensive For Loops

const markers = coords.map((coord) => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord.lat, coord.lng),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });     
})

// Declare your bounds outside the map method (previous for loop)

const   bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Iterate through markers and return coords for expanded viewport

markers.forEach((loc) =>{
     loc = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.position.lat(), loc.position.lng());
    return bounds.extend(loc);
});

map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
```

[image: Get JSBIN proof of concept]